# how to change checkbox color to black

Tags: android, checkbox

I have implemented checkbox programtically via for loop, how to change them to black color since other textviews are in black color its lucking odd, they are not in the xml ... there is one linear layout where these are getting added.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list_sted.size(); i++) {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
            cb.setText(""+list_sted.get(i));
            cb.setTextColor(R.color.Black);
            cb.setTextAppearance(getBaseContext(), android.R.attr.checkboxStyle);
            checkbox_lay.addView(cb);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: this helped me cb.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this.

```
cb.setTextColor(R.color.Black);
```

Use this one.

```
cb.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

or

```
cb.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

Comment: i was also thinking about this only

Comment: @ManishYadav or else you can use `cb.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.BLACK)`...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
cb.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

or From `color.xml`

```
cb.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
```